# How to create a large blurred shadow behind a TextView?

Tags: android, textview, material-design, shadow

I would like to create a quite large, soft shadow below my TextView. However I am not able to use a large enough shadow radius, as Android will crash if I set it to more than 25.0.

[image: This is an example of the shadow I want to create]

[image: This is the largest shadow radius I'm able to create]

The first of the images above is from our iOS app, and shows the shadow beneath the text as I want it. As you can see I'm not able to recreate this shadow effect on Android.

The XML style for the shadow effect is currently like this:

```
<style name="TextViewShadowEffectSoft">
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#DD000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">0.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">25.0</item>
</style>
```

Which is inflated to the AutoResizeTextView (ancestor of TextView) at creation:

```
 AutoResizeTextView title = (AutoResizeTextView) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text_shadow_soft, null);
```

Where text_shadow_soft.xml is:

```
com.app.models.AutoResizeTextView
style="@style/TextViewShadowEffectSoft" />
```

My app has a minimum API of 19.

EDIT: Crash log when setting *android:shadowRadius* higher than 25.0:

```
05-12 13:16:20.590 10679-10781/com.app E/rsC++: RS CPP error: Blur radius out of 0-25 pixel bound
05-12 13:16:20.593 10679-10781/com.app E/rsC++: RS CPP error (masked by previous error): Allocation creation failed
05-12 13:16:20.593 10679-10781/com.app E/rsC++: RS CPP error (masked by previous error): Allocation creation failed
05-12 13:16:20.593 10679-10781/com.app E/rsC++: RS CPP error (masked by previous error): Blur radius out of 0-25 pixel bound

                                                      --------- beginning of crash
05-12 13:16:20.594 10679-10781/com.app A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x28 in tid 10781 (RenderThread)
```

Appreciate all thoughts and input!

Comment: set `android:shadowRadius` to `50.0` works good in my phone.

Comment: Hi @JiangYD! It will crash if I set the `android:shadowRadius` to more than 25.0. See error above.

Comment: I think Android not limit it to 25, but your phone limit it. it hard to do blur shadow by yourself if you not family with graphic processing.

Comment: Oh, I see. Do you have any recommendations for alternative solutions? @JiangYD

Comment: did you try to add `android:layerType="software"` to textview?

Comment: That worked! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems some code related to your hardware limits it. So please use software rendering, add `android:layerType="software"` to your view.

Or in code use

```
myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel)

Comment: Be warned that this may make the render really ugly on some phones.

Comment: better possible ugly rendering then crash :), I have might crash cluster because of this